# For angular2 template form how to mandate user to select other than default value for dropdown and on reset button how to reset the values to default?

Tags: angular

I have following scenario where I have taken template form example from angular site and I wanted to achieve following  -

1. Mandate user to select other than default value from dropdown?
2. On reset click reset the values to default.

Plunkar example - https://plnkr.co/edit/k0nrnziXJa2xpQI41BjQ?p=preview

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="power">Hero Power</label>
            <select id="power"
              name="power" 
              class="form-control" 
              required
              [(ngModel)]="hero.power" 
              #power="ngModel">
              <option [value]="0" selected disabled>Please Select</option>
              <option *ngFor="let p of powers" [value]="p">{{p}}</option>
            </select>

            <div *ngIf="power.errors && power.touched && hero.power=='0'" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="hero.power=='0'">Power is required.</div>

   </div>
```

Component Code -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-form-template',
  templateUrl: './hero-form-template.component.html'
})
export class HeroFormTemplateComponent {

  powers = ['Really Smart', 'Super Flexible', 'Weather Changer'];

  hero = {name: 'Dr.', alterEgo: 'Dr. What', power: '0'};

}
```

Comment: Just don't set the default power value to 0, which is a valid value. Set it to null, and reset it to null. https://plnkr.co/edit/mYfGHEVfUC6XKwoPp7s0?p=preview

Comment: Thanks but in this case error message is getting displayed by default. I don't want to show error message by default only when it is changed/modified/touched.

Comment: I removed the conditions to make it clear that the field was indeed invalid. You can of course keep displaying the message only if the control is touched. That is irrelevant to your question and my suggestion.